# Reorder WordPress Plugin echo Order On Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

On my site, I have installed the plugins **Simple Share Buttons Adder** and **Source Affix**. Both of them adds something to the bottom of the post, currently SSBA go first and then Source Affix.

[image: Demo]

I want to reorder than and have the source before the share buttons.

How can I do it? thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change **Content Priority** value of Simple Share Buttons Plugin.

Admin >> Dashboard >> Settings >> Simple Share Buttons >> Advanced >> Content Priority textbox

Please find attached screenshot for more details

[image]